# Installation error rpm in mac 10.9.3

Tags: macos

I using `sudo port install rpm` to install the rpm in my mac(version 10.9.3), but when i use rpm, for example `rpm -qa`, it always gives me the error like:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Could somebody explain why and how to install correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rpm port is rather old (it depends on python 2.5 and perl 5.08 ) and is outdated as per [macports mail list in July 2012](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2012-July.txt) (i.e. it was outdated 2 years ago)

> Note that the rpm port contains the very old version 4.4.9 of the rpm program. Other ports exist that provide newer versions of rpm which you may want to use instead. None of the newer rpm ports have this particular bug.

Looking for new rpm ports by `port search rpm` shoes the highest port as rpm54 so try `sudo port install rpm54`

I would note that that latest is the same latest as two years ago I do not know if there is a higher rpm version elsewhere

Comment: I re-installed rpm54, and got another different error `error: cannot open Packages(0) index: No such file or directory(2)
 DB: Berkeley DB 5.3.21: (May 11, 2012)
error: cannot open Packages database in /opt/local/var/lib/rpm`

Comment: That is a separate question - was that run under sudo?